# Tkinter checkbox dependencies (can't check one box without having another checked)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have three checkboxes A,B and C. Checkbox A cannot be checked unless C is already checked. However, C can be checked even if A is not checked.

I am currently setting A and C as the same variable, but that does not take care of the case where C is checked and A is not.

Comment: Ok,  you've explained your requirements. What part of the solution are you struggling with? Please show a [mcve] that illustrates the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using a `command` on `checkbutton` C so that whenever it is updated it changes the `state` of `checkbutton` A.

See below for an example:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.check1 = Checkbutton(self.master, text="A", state="disabled")
        self.check2 = Checkbutton(self.master, text="B")
        self.check3 = Checkbutton(self.master, text="C", command=self.command)
        self.check1.pack()
        self.check2.pack()
        self.check3.pack()
    def command(self):
        if self.check1.cget("state") == "disabled":
            self.check1.configure(state="normal")
        else:
            self.check1.configure(state="disabled")


root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```